# DynamicRows component doesn't show saved data on edit form (Adminhtml)

Tags: adminhtml, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form, dynamic-rows

The ui form component works good on "New" action but, if I save this:

[image: New action]

Then, the edit action shows this:

[image: Edit action]

**The data is being saved correctly in my custom table after submitting the "New" action.**

Here is the `dynamicRows` section of my ui form layout:

```
   <container name="attribute_code_container">
      <dynamicRows name="attribute_code">
        <settings>
            <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
            <label translate="true">Attributes / Fields</label>
            <columnsHeader>false</columnsHeader>
            <addButton>true</addButton>
            <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add attribute</addButtonLabel>
            <deleteProperty>false</deleteProperty>
            <dndConfig>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</param>
            </dndConfig>
        </settings>
        <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="attribute_code" formElement="select">
              <formElements>
                  <select>
                      <settings>
                          <options class="Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Attribute"/>
                      </settings>
                  </select>
              </formElements>
            </field>
            <actionDelete>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">actionDelete</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Delete</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </actionDelete>
        </container>
      </dynamicRows>
    </container>
```

The `Vendor\Module\Model\Source\Attribute` class seems to be OK,try with `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno` (For example) I get the same result.

What is wrong with the `dynamicRows` component and how can I set an instruction to get the data from my custom table the right way?

Comment: Could you add full content of ui form xml, `getData` method in DataProvider class, and Save controller? That will make us easier to help.

Comment: @TuVan the answer is already posted.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you posted enough information, I was able to help you earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout XML of the dynamicGrid was OK but, because of using a select/option element to show the data, **it was expecting an ARRAY** and I was providing a string on my `dataSource`.

Unserializing the data returned by my database made the trick:

```
public function getData(): array
{
    if (!isset($this->loadedData)) {
        $this->loadedData = [];

        foreach ($this->collection->getItems() as $item) {
            $this->loadedData[$item->getData('entity_id')] = $item->getData();

            $attributeCodes = $this->serializerJson->unserialize(
                $this->loadedData[$item->getData('entity_id')]['attribute_code']
            );

            $this->loadedData[$item->getData('entity_id')]['attribute_code'] = $attributeCodes;
        }
    }

    return $this->loadedData;
}
```

Where `$this->serializerJson` is an object of `\Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json`.

If you have similar issues, the thing you have to double-check is the implementation of your `dataSource`.